# Define Ballerina ecord type where fields have a predefined values

Tags: ballerina

```
type JsonSchema record{|
    string 'type;
    json properties;
|};

type ArraySchema record{|
    string 'type;
    json items;
|};
```

Please check the above record types. In both records `'type` should be `"object"` and `"array"` respectively. However, according to the above definition, the user is able to put any string to those fields. How do we constrain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type JsonSchema record{|
    "object" 'type = "object";
    json properties;
|};

type ArraySchema record{|
    "array" 'type = "array";
    json items;
|};
```

We can define the field using singleton type and add default value as shown here.